# Как сохранить и восстановить состояние формы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, форма

Пишу плагин формы для Wordpress, в админке конструктор формы, где можно добавлять/удалять/менять местами поля. Нужно сохранять в БД все опции и порядок полей формы, а затем на странице получить эти настройки и отобразить форму.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой алгоритм действий, чтобы это реализовать?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_option если я правильно понял проблему. И не забывать про https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/plugin/osnovy/udalenie

Comment: Использовать готовый плагин, которых масса: Contact From 7, WPForms, Quform, Gravity Forms и т.д. Код этих известных плагинов не содержит дыр по безопасности.

Comment: Мне нужно написать плагин, вопрос в этом. Как сохранить состояние полей формы?

Comment: Ну здесь наверное будет иметь смысл посмотреть, как это реализовано в уже существующих плагинах. Можете хранить как сериализованный массив, внутрь массива и записывайте необходимые Вам опции, тот же порядок поля, тип поля и так далее.

Comment: Можно в массив: тег, атрибуты. Потом в json и в бд. Можно тупо form.outerHTML и в бд. Можно еще каким-то извращенным способом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо создать некое абстрактное представление полей формы в виде массива, содержащего порядок и описание полей формы. Что-то вроде

```
$form = [
    [
        'element'  => 'input',
        'type'     => 'text',
        'name'     => 'Username',
        'required' => true,
    ],
    [
        'element'  => 'input',
        'type'     => 'text',
        'name'     => 'Email',
        'required' => true,
    ],
    [
        'element'  => 'button',
        'type'     => 'submit',
        'name'     => 'Submit',
    ],
];
```

и сохранять этот массив в опцию с помощью `update_option()`.

Генерировать актуальную форму нужно из него.

Comment: Да, идея верная. Можете подсказать инструмент для такого представления формы? Наверняка уже есть что-то такое.

Comment: Инструмент тут простой - php, js, ajax. Вы же свой плагин пишете.